# Why is WITH required when using NOLOCK on a remote table call?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I ran into an issue today trying to access a remote table using `NOLOCK`. I received this error:

```
Remote table-valued function calls are not allowed.
```

Upon Googling the issue, I found that adding `WITH (NOLOCK)` corrects the issue. I'm wondering why that is?

**SQL:**

```
SELECT *
FROM [LINKED_SRV].[DB1].[dbo].[REMOTE_TABLE] WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Comment: Are you saying `WITH` is not required when querying a table on the current server?

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer Are you sure? http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d0eeb/1

Comment: It appears I'm incorrect, answer removed.

Comment: All of my other queries do not use `WITH` and I use `NOLOCK` in all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation for table hints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx):

> **Important**
>
> Omitting the WITH keyword is a deprecated feature: This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.
>
> The following table hints are allowed with and without the WITH keyword: NOLOCK, READUNCOMMITTED, UPDLOCK, REPEATABLEREAD, SERIALIZABLE, READCOMMITTED, TABLOCK, TABLOCKX, PAGLOCK, ROWLOCK, NOWAIT, READPAST, XLOCK, and NOEXPAND. When these table hints are specified without the WITH keyword, the hints should be specified alone.

The documentation states that for your attempted query, omitting the `WITH` keyword is allowed. Based on that, I would consider this a bug. However, the documentation also states that this feature is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of SQL Server, so you should not expect this bug to be fixed in any other way than by a change to the documentation.

I suspect that the parser sees `FROM server.database.schema.table (` and decides that this is a call to a user-defined function, therefore an error, and never gets to the point where it sees that `NOLOCK` is not a function argument.

Comment: Good to know. If we upgraded to SQL Server 2012 right now, we'd be up that proverbial creek without a paddle. Thanks @hvd.

Comment: Great answer, thanks for the clarification!  Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

NOLOCK

This table hint, also known as READUNCOMMITTED, is applicable to SELECT statements only. NOLOCK indicates that no shared locks are issued against the table that would prohibit other transactions from modifying the data in the table.

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/using-nolock-and-readpast-table-hints-in-sql-server/6185492